# Pass Fail for a range of cells for Text

Tags: excel-formula

I am using the following formula for a range of cells that I want a "Pass", "Fail" or empty cell when the field is empty.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(I7:O7,"")=ROWS(I7:O7), "Pass", IF(COUNTIF(I7:O7,"Fail"), "Fail", ""))
```

I am getting the blank cell when the range is empty as well as the Fail when one of the columns is Fail within the range, but cannot get it to show "Pass" if all the columns in the range pass. The only columns that will use "Pass", "Fail" or "", are I7, L7 and O7. I would then copy the formula down the other rows. 
This is to obtain an Overall Pass/Fail, just in case 1 field is Fail I want it to show an overall Fail, but if all fields Pass I want it to show an Overall Pass.

thanks in advance.

Comment: then you need to change the `""` in the countif to `"Pass"` : `...COUNTIF(I7:O7,"Pass")...`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - but I am still getting the same result. The cell is blank and not showing "Pass". Here is the rev formula: =IF(COUNTIF(I5:O5,"Pass")=COLUMNS(I5:O5), "Pass", IF(COUNTIF(I5:O5,"Fail"), "Fail", ""))

Comment: Change the `ROWS(` to `COULMNS(`

Comment: Tried that and still getting the same result. Can't get a PASS in the field. Only getting the FAIL and empty cell. Those 2 cells are populating correctly.

Comment: Then check your data to ensure there is not a space or other non-printable character that would make it not find the `Pass`.  As you can see from my answer it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(I7:O7,"Pass")=COLUMNS(I7:O7), "Pass", IF(COUNTIF(I7:O7,"Fail"), "Fail", ""))
```

[image]

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer, @RutabagaSue